# ReferenceError: global is not defined with Stream and Angular 7.1

Tags: getstream-io

I'm trying to use Stream with Angular 7, however I am getting the following error.

> ReferenceError: global is not defined
>   ReferenceError: global is not defined
>       at Object../node_modules/faye/src/util/browser/event.js (event.js:45)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at Object../node_modules/faye/src/protocol/client.js (client.js:8)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at Object../node_modules/faye/src/faye_browser.js (faye_browser.js:9)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at Object../node_modules/getstream/lib/lib/client.js (client.js:25)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at Object../node_modules/getstream/lib/getstream.js (getstream.js:6)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:83)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
>       at zone.js:873
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:16147)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)

I am using the package "getstream" from npm version 4.1.0.

Here is a snippet of code and how I am referencing it.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Constants } from './../constants';
import * as stream from 'getstream';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ActivityService {
  userToken: string;
  streamClient: stream.Client;

  constructor(public azureService: AzureService) { 
    console.log("Activity Service");
  }

  async initializeClient() {
    try {
      await this.getUserToken();

      if (this.userToken) {
        this.streamClient = await stream.connect(Constants.streamKey, this.userToken, Constants.streamAppId);
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log('Error creating stream client - ', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

I've tried declaring global but I am not sure what else to try.  What's the proper way to import and use Stream in this case?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This looks like an Angular issue. They do offer some workarounds for this.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8160
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827#issuecomment-386154063

```
(window as any).global = window;
```

Comment: Thanks adding that line to my polyfills.ts resolved the problem.

Comment: Thanks, guys. saved the day in minutes